# Worker thread is terminated by main thread as soon as I call a function node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I'm trying to have a worker thread handle rounds of a question based game by receiving data from the main thread on a Node server. However every time I call a function on the worker thread it receives the terminate signal from the main thread.

```
parentPort.on('message', (msg) =>{
  HEADER = msg.HEAD;
  console.log(msg);
  //console.log(QuestionSet);
  if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[0])
  {

  }
  else if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[1])
  {

  }
  else if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[2])
  {

  }
  else if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[3])
  {
    QuestionSet = msg.DATA.QUESTIONS;
    SessionID = msg.DATA.SESSIONID;
    console.log(QuestionSet);
    chooseQuestion();
    //Start Game
  }
```

the termination only occurs when chooseQuestion() is not commented out leading me to believe this is my problem. I could be wrong, I'm just trying to cobble something together fast to be done with school. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Kiran, could you please include the actual error message / stack trace that you're getting?

Comment: Do you understand that the Worker thread cannot call code in the main program.  It must have all of its own code.  So, if `chooseQuestion()` is not in the worker thread itself, then that will throw a referenceError.  It's unclear why this type of setup would need worker threads.  Worker threads are for CPU heavy code.

Comment: @taleodor `Ended Worker
Error: Worker stopped with exit code 1
    at Worker.<anonymous> (S:\Programming\JavaScript\AdventuresInJS\Small_Projects\QuestionGuess\QuestionGuessV4\Private\server.js:242:21)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Worker.[kOnExit] (internal/worker.js:165:10)
    at Worker.<computed>.onexit (internal/worker.js:116:51)`   is this what you meant? sorry I don't quite get how these comments are supposed to work

Comment: @jfriend00 yes the chooseQuestion() function is part of the script I have written specifically for the worker threads handling rounds, this is why I'm confused. At the moment it seems to me that you have to have it do one thing, close and then open another worker to do the rest? If that's the case I will probably have to find another approach. Thanks for the response

Comment: @KiranForrest - There is no such limitation with a workerThread.  It can easily be used to do multiple things.  You need to trap the error better so we can see exactly what's going on.  You can do that one of two ways.  You can put a `try/catch` around the call to `chooseQuestion()` and then in the catch(e) { console.log(e);} so you can see the full strack trace that's causing the problem.  Or, where you create the worker do `worker.on("error", () => {console.log(error)});` so you can output the error coming back from the worker.  I would recommend implementing both.

Comment: And, show us your `chooseQuestion()` code since that is apparently where the problem is.

Comment: @jfriend00 Upon using the try/catch block I realize it was my error and I simply forgot to load a library. Sorry for wasting your time. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you always implement my second suggestion above with `worker.on('error', ...)`, any time you create a worker, you will automatically get a console message with any serious uncaught error in the worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it helped you find your problem.

A sudden termination of a worker like this is likely because there's some sort of uncaught exception in the worker, but you aren't catching it to log what it is.  It's very useful to always have these exceptions logged.  In your main program, they would often get logged for you, but not always the case in a worker.  There are two ways for you to make sure this error gets logged so you can see exactly what it is.  One general purpose way that you should probably use for all your workers and one specific way for your particular function that has a problem.

Here's the general purpose way.  When you create your worker thread, always add this:

```
worker.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
    // do something else here like exit your program
});
```

This will give you console output for any unhandled and fatal error in the worker thread.

---

Now, in your specific situation, you know that it's when you call `chooseQuestion();` that the problem occurs, you can also just put a `try/catch` around that so you can catch and log the error:

```
parentPort.on('message', (msg) =>{
  try {
    HEADER = msg.HEAD;
    console.log(msg);
    //console.log(QuestionSet);
    if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[0])
    {

    }
    else if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[1])
    {

    }
    else if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[2])
    {

    }
    else if (HEADER === HEADERSWORKER[3])
    {
      QuestionSet = msg.DATA.QUESTIONS;
      SessionID = msg.DATA.SESSIONID;
      console.log(QuestionSet);
      chooseQuestion();
      //Start Game
    }
  } catch(e) {
     console.log(e);
  }
});
```